# Using Azure AD B2C Services and Java Programming Language , I want to implement User functionality

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-ad-b2c

Using Azure AD B2C Services, I want to implement User functionality using Java Programming Language.

Functionality Given below.

User Registration
User Login
Reset/Forget Password
Change Password
User Profile Update
Access other API through an access token
As per my finding in all  Microsoft documents,  For all the above operations it's redirecting on Microsoft UI.
Apart from this in my scenario, we don't want to expose  client Id, Secret Id, Tenant Id in URL to end-user.
Please suggest right Java  SDK library or Rest Endpoint to achieve above features using Azure AD B2C service

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot there is a starter made by microsoft to integrate with Azure AD B2C. A full example of using it in [their docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-oidc).

However as you said it is redirecting to Azure website for login etc, and I advise you to do it this way, they follow the [OAuth2 protocol](https://oauth.net/2/), and the redirections are made to enhance security. Hence flows with redirections are more secure than ones with API calls.

If you really don't want to redirect to Azure, then you will have to implement the Resource Owner Password Credentials user flow (stated as ROPC mostly in their docs). It is a standard OAuth2 flow so you will find a lot of way to do it (the azure ad b2c starter migth even do it directly, but i'm not sure for the ROPC part).

Then for password resetting, profile update etc you will have to call the Microsoft Azure Api ([here's the jdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java)). Any actions you can make on the azure UI you can make with the api here (azure graph api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api)).

You should have everything to start now!